# Isomorphisms between minimal $A_\infty$-algebras having identical $k$-truncations

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homological-algebra, a-infinity-algebras

Let $A_m =(A,0,m_2,m_3,\dots)$ and $A_n=(A,0,n_2,n_3,\dots)$ be two $A_\infty$-structures on a vector space $A$. Assume that

i) $A_m$ and $A_n$ are isomorphic, and

ii) $A_m$ and $A_n$ have the same $k$-truncation,  say $m_2 = n_2,\dots,m_k =n_k$.

Can one show that there exists an $A_\infty$-isomorphism between $A_m$ and $A_n$ which is of the form $(id,0,\dots,0,f_k,f_{k+1},\dots)$?

An equivalent form: is $(m_{k+1}-n_{k+1})$ a boundary in the Hochschild cochain complex of the associative algebra $(A,m_2)$?